# Group by expressions with condition - Linq

Tags: c#, database, oracle, linq, lambda

I am trying to use LINQ and LAMBDA expressions for querying tables from ORACLE database. When using group by clauses, the time to fetch data is growing considerably.

In the following code block, there is a group by expression which contains if condition.

```
using (var entities = new Entities())
{
    var result = entities.myTable.Where(a => a.COLUMNONE > 1)
        .GroupBy(g => new { columnForGrouping = (g.COLUMNTWO > 50 ? "Group1" : "Group2") })
        .Select(sel => new {
            columnGroup = sel.Key.columnForGrouping, 
            count = sel.Count()
        }).ToList();
}
```

I am wondering how efficient is this type of group by expressions? And, does it have a better one?

Comment: BTW no need to create the anonymous object if grouping by only one value. Can do instead `.GroupBy(g => g.COLUMNTWO > 50 ? "Group1" : "Group2")`

Comment: I don't think there is an intrinsically better way to do it. your performance impact may also be caused by indexes (or rather the lack thereof) in your database, etc. there are too many factors to consider here.

Comment: It looks fine. Please show the sql of the query executed and its explain plan?

Comment: What is the output query? Could the query itself benefit from indexes?

Comment: The output is like thar (the name of columns are edited). I hope it will help.

`SELECT 
1 AS "C1", 
"GroupBy1"."K1" AS "C2", 
"GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C3"
FROM ( SELECT 
 "Filter1"."K1" AS "K1", 
 COUNT("Filter1"."A1") AS "A1"
 FROM ( SELECT 
  CASE WHEN (( CAST( "Extent1"."COLUMNTWO" AS number(10,0))) > 50) THEN 'Group1' ELSE 'Group2' END AS "K1", 
  1 AS "A1"
  FROM "DB"."MYTABLE" "Extent1"
  WHERE ("Extent1"."COLUMNONE" > 1)
 )  "Filter1"
 GROUP BY "K1"
)  "GroupBy1"`

Comment: @rayrayroy - What is the type of `COLUMNTWO`?

Comment: @GiladGreen It is `NUMBER(3,0)`

Comment: You could try moving the ToList() after the Where clause, to load the objects into the memory, which would make the grouping faster

Comment: @LiviuBoboia I know this way, but I don't prefer it. because memory is accumulating too much. There are millions of data coming when I use Tolist() before grouping the data. I must group them at database layer.

Comment: is this the actual query, or are you trying to achieve something else, because this can done by creating 2 objects, one where g.COLUMNTWO > 50 and another where g.COLUMNTWO <= 50

Comment: @LiviuBoboia This is not the whole query. I shared it for explaining the issue. If you divide this query into two statement like you said, it will take more time than grouped one. Moreover, we don't prefer to get datas with multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

The following instruction might cause the performance issue:

```
CAST( "Extent1"."COLUMNTWO" AS number(10,0)))
```

Cast in sql might produce unexpected behavior performance-wise. I suggest you to use a different data-type.

Comment: In almost all of my comparisons, lambda makes type-casting. I don't think that, performance differs because of casting, but I will check that too. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I reviewed my complicated query. There were lots of CAST action. Then, I cleared the code. Performance was increased about thirty percent. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: I'm glad i helped.

Answer (score -1):

Linq sql queries are not very efficient, especially with group by and joins. Would highly recommend optimize a query and use that directly.

In one of my cases that reduced time from 12sec to 3secs.

Comment: Why aren't they efficient? They can be as long as you do your work as programmer well. Bad code produces bad queries.

Comment: I agree with Patrick. If you don't optimize your query, whatever you use, your query will run slower.